# ¿Como llamar funciones con el evento onclick? - Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
<script>
        function pausaplay(){
  document.getElementById('demo45').play();
  document.getElementById('demo14').pause();
}
</script>
```

```html
<input value="Mirar Havana" onclick="if(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display != ''){this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = '';this.value = 'Mirar Havana';}else{this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = 'none'; this.value = 'Mirar Rockabye';}" type="button">
```

yo lo he intentado asi:

```js
<script>
function pausaplay(){
if(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display != ''){this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = '';this.value = 'Mirar Havana';}else{this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = 'none'; this.value = 'Mirar Rockabye';}
  document.getElementById('demo45').play();
  document.getElementById('demo14').pause();
}
</script>

<input value="Mirar Havana" onclick="pausaplay()" type="button">
```

pero no creo que asi sea, estoy aprendiendo javascript hasta ahora, por eso tengo muchas dudas... gracias por su respeusta

Comment: A que te refires con juntar 2 onclick? Personalemente no entendi.

Comment: osea no juntar 2 onclick, sino el onclick del input ponerlo con el javascript para que aga 3 funciones a la vez

Comment: Y el segundo codigo que mostrates, no te funciona?

Comment: no me funciona, hasta ahora estoy aprendiendo,y tengo dudas asi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si entendí bien, la manera en que lo hiciste es correcta.

```
<input value="Mirar Havana" onclick="pausaplay();" type="button">
```

Dentro del onclick agregas el nombre de tu función a ejecutar, obviamente tendras que haber enlazado tu archivo javascript al html mediante:

```
<script src="nombre-de-tu-archivo.js"></script>
```

O haber escrito tu codigo js tal cual lo hiciste.

Answer (score 1):

Para saber que tu función código es correcto y tu función es llamada puedes usar la consola de JS del navegador y las funciones asociadas. Si el código es correcto se ejecutará, si hay errores te lo indica.

Ejemplo:

HTML:

```
<p onclick="test()">Clic aquí</p>
```

JS:

```
function test() {
    console.log( "Ejecutando función test()" );
}
```

Resultado (en console):

```
Ejecutando función test()
```

Si tienes varias funciones que quieres asociar al mismo evento, por ejemplo un clic en cierto elemento de la página, basta con que hagas las llamadas a esas funciones dentro de una que es llamada por el evento. Por ejemplo:

HTML:

```
<p onclick="test()">Clic aquí</p>
```

JS:

```
function test() {
    console.log( "Ejecutando función test()" );

    //Llamada a otras funciones:
    rojo();
    verde();
}

function rojo() {
    console.log( "Ejecutando rojo()" );
}
function verde() {
    console.log( "Ejecutando verde()" );
}
```

Resultado (en console):

```
Ejecutando función test()
Ejecutando rojo()
Ejecutando verde()
```

Comment: muchas gracias...